# Activex control for MS word Spell Checker

Tags: javascript, jsp, vbscript, activex

I am getting error when trying to call CreateObject("Word.Application"), its not able to create Word application object on win7   running inside IE9.0(compatible view checked)and i have MS office word 2007 installed on My PC. I a calling this from a VB script which is called from a web page (jsp).

Any ideas greatly appreciated.!

```
Set ObjSpellChck= CreateObject("Word.Application")

        If (IsEmpty(ObjSpellChck)) Then 
            MsgBox "Could not create Spell Check Object"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Err.Number <> 0 OR Err.Number = 429 Then
            MsgBox "Please install the 'Spell Check' ActiveX Control", 64
            Err.Clear
            On Error GOTO 0
            Exit Sub 
        End If
```

Comment: Is this code running on the client or on the server?

Comment: This is runnning on client side IE 9.0

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Word control is not marked as "safe for scripting", so it cannot be used from a web page.

You should really stop using VBScript. It will not work in browsers other than Internet Explorer, and is likely to stop working entirely under newer versions of Explorer. (There are already some reports that it may not work reliably in IE10.)